# Splitting an array of email attachments to send using C# Outlook Interop

Tags: c#, arrays, email

Currently I have a fine working code which sends email with all .pdf files as attachments from specific folder.

```
DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);
FileInfo[] files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.pdf");

Outlook.Application outapp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem mail = outapp.CreateItemFromTemplate(filePath) as 
Outlook.MailItem;

foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
mail.Attachments.Add(filePath + "\\" + file.Name, 
Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
}
```

I want to make it when the attachments are more than 7, to send multiple emails with maximum of 7 in each.I had an idea to use `Take()` and `Skip()` to split the array of files, but that would not be so great solution.

I'm open for suggestions :P

Best Regards,
Alexander

Comment: Maybe you should use `for` instead of `foreach` and send a mail for every 7th iteration of files?

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria I can easily do that, but somehow I need to attach the files too. And honestly, I have no idea how to do that :P

Comment: You can send mail from `for` block when current count of iterations will be divided on 7. You will add attachment to mail for everyone iteration and will send mail when count of iterations will be a multiple of 7.